# Active Directory reading user attributes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to let my winform system to authonticate using username of the person in active directory. i am using now the following code. But the result is null !!

```
 private static string LDAP_Connection = "corp.mycompany.global";
 private static string LDAP_Path = "LDAP://OU=USERS,OU=BT,OU=EC,OU=tres,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=global";



 static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
        {
            // create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings  

            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP_Connection);
            ldapConnection.Path = LDAP_Path;
            ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

            return ldapConnection;
        } 



public static void RetreiveUserInfoAdvanced()
{
    try
    {
        // create LDAP connection object  

        DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();

        // create search object which operates on LDAP connection object  
        // and set search object to only find the user specified  

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
        //search.Filter = "(mail  =" + _userlogin + ")";
        search.Filter = "mail  = a.ghew@mycompany.com";

        // create results objects from search object  

        //SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        string[] requiredProperties = new string[] { "cn", "mail" };  

            foreach (String property in requiredProperties)   
               search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);  

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();  

            if (result != null)  
            {  
               foreach (String property in requiredProperties)  
                  foreach (Object myCollection in result.Properties[property])   
                     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-20} : {1}", property, myCollection.ToString())); 

            }
    }
}
```

i used Ad Explorer with the same data, everything is find an working fine and i can reach the required data. But from my system  can't.

Comment: By the way. with using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, it works fine, but ofcourse is limited for the attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your AD environment, but I did the following in a similar configuration:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
search.Filter = "(mail=a.ghew@mycompany.com)";
search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

Give that a go?  Basically remove your whitespace in the filter expression and ensure you have traversal enabled.